# Use of "$or" condition is not working

Tags: php, mongodb

I am developing a search portal, so I need to find the searched text on more than one field.

I am trying to use the advanced query of MongoDB in PHP.

My code is:

```
$mongo = new MongoDBCONN();
$jobCollection = $mongo->select('jobs', $mongo); 

$advanceQuery=array('orgId' => '21')
$query_q=array('$or'=>array(
    array("jobTitle"=>new MongoRegex("/$search/i")),
    array("jobLocationCity"=>new MongoRegex("/$search/i")),
    array('jobLocationCountry'=>new MongoRegex("/$search/i"))
));
$advanceQuery=array_merge($advanceQuery,$query_q);
$jobCollection->find($advanceQuery);
```

It returns NULL every time, whereas MongoRegex is working fine, because when I use it to search on only one field it works.

$search is post as input text.

Comment: Why do you use `array_merge`?

Comment: because there are many other parameter i am trying also based on conditions like if date is also in search it will get added in array to search, and this is the just like in sql we did if(date is available in search parameter)  "$query = $query ."and date = '24-10-2011'";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on my own, actually this was a version problem. I was using 1.4.4, but after update to 1.7.4 it is working. On the mongo website I found that the "or" operator was included only from version 1.7.x onwards.

Answer (score 1):

```
$regexObj = new MongoRegex("/$search_term/i");

$where  = array(
             '$or' => array(
                          array("Name" => $regexObj), 
                          array("image.caption.text" => $regexObj), 
                          array("image.user.username" => $regexObj)
              )
);
$cursor = $collection->find($where);

// Parsing the results
while ($cursor->hasNext())
{
    $obj            = $cursor->getNext();
    $profile_image = $obj['image']['user']['profile_picture'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to combine the regex with another operator, you need to use the `$regex` clause. That one is missing in your code example. Please read again about how to [query with regulars expressions](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions).

Comment: ok for testing i have removed other conditions and trying this     $query_q=array('orgId' => '21','$or'=>array(
       array("jobTitle"=>new MongoRegex("/$search/i")),
       array("jobLocationCity"=>new MongoRegex("/$search/i")),
       array('jobLocationCountry'=>new MongoRegex("/$search/i"))
      ));                                                                  but stil result =0

Comment: first of all thx for your response now i am using only this much                                                          $mongo = new MongoDBCONN();
$jobCollection = $mongo->select('jobs', $mongo); 


$query_q=array('orgId' => '21','$or'=>array(
       array("jobTitle"=>'Senior Front End Engineer'),
       array("jobLocationCity"=>'Gurgaon'),
      ));

$jobCollection->find($query_q);   but result is same